# How to type a capital letter from the extended Latin alphabet in OS X

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I'm aware that if you want to type a character from extended Latin alphabet in OS X (like in the word `über`), you just press the basic symbol key for a while and then a popup occurs with the list of extended symbols.

[image]

But, I would like to type this letter in uppercase. I press the symbol key (for Example <kbd>U</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>), then see the character popup. Then I press the number of the required symbol, although I am given an `@` sign instead of the uppercase `Ü`.

How can I type capital letters with accents? I don't want to copy and paste symbols that I require every time from the web or developer console.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key then the number corresponding.  It works just fine.  I think you are forgetting to let go of the <kbd>shift</kbd> before hitting the number.  Hence the unexpected output.

[image: Type diacritics]

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then, after popup *let go of the shift key* and hit the corresponding number.
Ü ← result

Comment: Or, if you have a numeric keypad, press the number there, even if you are still holding the shift.

Comment: @GEdgar good one.  For example, the Apple wired keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a while for the answer but didn't get lucky. It turned out that you have to press the basic symbol key for a while to request the system popup.

When holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and basic letter key, press left/right arrows to choose necessary symbol. Then when you choose, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

So for Æ sign you have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>right/left arrow</kbd>.

That's it. Now you can type `ÜBÊR` and so on.